# Boundary operator in regex PHP up to four occurrences of the character

Tags: regex, character, boundary

```
<?php 
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\pL)(.){1,4}(?!\pL)/','%','Pamiętam i tak będę z tobą jestem jestem i czuweam dfgd....');
?>
```

How to do it, to if `jestem` will to have from 1 to 4 characters, to not output this?

```
((?<!\pL)(?!\pL)){1,4}
```

I want have result such:

```
Pamiętam jestem jestem czuweam dfgd....
```

Comment: He has to replace all words that are not even words but have 1 to 4 characters. I want have this: example .go. example on example % example, because .go. have 4 characters.

Comment: See my answer below - does it work? If yes, please accept. Else, add details *to the question body*.

Comment: Thanks, then yourself rather I can handle alone later probably.

Comment: Could you just let me know what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: All OK. All right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
$s = 'Pamiętam i tak będę z tobą jestem jestem i czuweam dfgd.... Teraz idę do kina. A teraz nie idę.';
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\S)\S{1,4}(?!\S)/u','%', $s);
// => Pamiętam % % % % % jestem jestem % czuweam dfgd.... Teraz % % kina. % teraz % %
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<!\S)` -  there must be a whitespace symbol or start of string immediately before...
- `\S{1,4}` - 1 to 4 non-whitespace chars
- `(?!\S)` - immediately after those 1-4 chars, there must be a whitespace symbol or end of string.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/FAI7Xi).

Do not forget a `/u` UNICODE modifier since you are working with Unicode strings.

Comment: dfgd.... have 8 characters, i want have, to not change. Now count as 4 characters and change. I want dfgd.... as whole, not %.....

Comment: @Neutral: Please check again.